# Custom XIB cell for UITableView stuttering / hitching on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm registering a XIB for my table's cell view. Nothing fancy, pretty straight forward little cell view with a couple of UIImageView and some UILabel. Things work as expected, but when I scroll I get a lot of stutter / hitching. I did some profiling and it appears that a lot of time is being spent in [UITableView  _dequeueReusableTyper:withIdentifier:] . I've commented out all the code from my cellForRowAtIndexPath method except for simply dequeue and return of cell, and the stutter is still there. So the culprit is indeed this dequeue call stack. But I'm not sure how I can optimize this to run smoothly other than simplifying my cell view in my XIB, which may not be an option (or a difficult one). Am I missing anything here that I should try out?

Dequeue code:

```
UIMyTableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UIMyListTableCellView" bundle:nil];
    [table registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
}
cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
```

Comment: What sort of images are you putting in your cell - what size / resolution?

Comment: Can you post some code? Perhaps there's an error in the way the dequeue is happening.

Comment: Small images. One image is 100x100 pixels, and there are two smaller ones of 30x30 pixels.

Comment: My dequeue code:

`UIMyTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UIMyListTableCellView" bundle:nil];
        [table registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
    }
    cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the stutter and get a high scrolling framerate. For others who are having similar issues, the problem was in using the custom XIB for the table cell. Apparently this code path is not optimized, or something is bugged. I replaced this by implementing my own drawRect method for the custom table cell and now things are blazing at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` once, you will be calling it each time `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"]` return `nil`.

Why do you start with `self.tableView` then switch to `table`? Are these the same object?

If they are not the same object, then `[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"]` will always return `nil` and you will always be calling `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

---

Try moving `-registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` to another method like `-viewDidLoad` or wrapping some protection against repeated calls.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL nibRegistered;
```

…

```
if (!self.nibRegistered) {
    self.nibRegistered = YES;
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UIMyListTableCellView" bundle:nil];
    [table registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry about the different table object references. Yes they are indeed the same, I just messed up while copying the code.

As for the registration of nibs, I remember the nib registration was getting lost in certain cases (i think on table reload or something). But anyway, this is really not an issue, I'm not seeing any over-registration calls happening. Furthermore it doesn't change performance either way, which is what I'm trying to fix.